# Error in dynamic programming problem.What does " Runtime error: exit code is -1073741571 " mean?

Tags: c++14, dynamic-programming

I need help in debugging my code for the problem - https://codeforces.com/contest/520/problem/B

I have tried solving it using dynamic programming but i am getting error.I want to know why i am getting runtime error?

The idea i have used is that :

1. if n becomes equal to m i am not required to press any more buttons;
2. if n becomes greater than m then the only way i can get to m is by subtracting 1 everytime. Thus (n-m) moves.
3. and for n < m, i have recursively called min of both moves possible+1

The error i am getting is - Runtime error: exit code is -1073741571

The code i have implemented.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long int

ll dfs(ll n, ll m){
    if(n == 0)  return INT_MAX;
    if(n == m){
        return 0;
    }
    if(n > m) {
        return abs(n-m);
    }
    return 1+min(dfs(2*n,m),dfs(n-1,m));
}

int main(){
    ll n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    ll ans = dfs(n ,m);
    cout << ans << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Runs fine https://ideone.com/zsxZsX

Comment: @DeiDei Yes you provided 10 1 where n > m initially therefore runs fine as returns abs(n-m) at the very first call...give 4 6 as input it will exceed time limit.Probably going in some endless recursive loop.I am not able to figure why is it so .

Comment: `dfs(n-1,m)`. `m` never changes but `n` is decreased by one. Entering value 4 and 6 will keep going until `n` rolls around to `std::numeric_limits<ll>::max()`. Thus probably causing the stack overflow

Comment: You should also consider using `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` and `std::int64_t` instead.

Comment: I didn't consider the exit condition of `n == 0`. Still, if the user were to enter `n <= 0` this code would be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Converting the exit code `-1073741571` to hex (e.g. using http://www.free-test-online.com/binary/signed_converter.html : select "Signed", enter the number, press "Dec2Hex"), you will get the respective Windows error code, which is `C00000FD`.

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55, this is:

```
0xC00000FD
STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW
A new guard page for the stack cannot be created.
```

Most likely, the stack overflow results from your recursion being too deep: Each recursive function call stores some data on the stack (registers, return address, etc.), which after a huge number of recursions is just to much. This is why, you should prefer to avoid recursion where possible.

A solution might be, to try to reformulate your solution using an iterative approach (i.e. a `for`or `while` loop.

Comment: Yes i understand that the function is going in some endless recursive calls thus occupying the stack. But the constraint are not that large and my function should certainly get into some if and should return from its call.Can you figure why it is not so?

Comment: @odd_Hooligans See my comment below your question for the probable explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Coming to the issue with the algorithm that causes the stack overflow:

At some point, you will call `dfs(n=1, m=6)`, which in

```
 return 1+min(dfs(2*n,m),dfs(n-1,m));
```

will call `dfs(0, 6)`, which returns immediately due to n==0, and `dfs(2, 6)`. This will call `dfs(4, 6)`, which we ignore for now, and `dfs(1, 6)`, which brings is a state you already have been in. This is the endless recursion.

You might want to consider to avoid pushing blue if `n==2` except if `m==1`. Maybe, some special handling for `n==1` might also doe the trick instead.

Comment: Thank you.Your comment helped.